# A simple example for someone who wants to understand Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am looking for a manageably understandable example for someone who wants to learn Dynamic Programming. [There are nice answers here about what is dynamic programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065433/what-is-dynamic-programming). The fibonacci sequence is a great example, but it is too small to scratch the surface. It looks a great subject to learn about although I haven't taken the algorithms class yet, hopefully it is on my list for the spring.

Answer (score 30):

Check out this site: [Dynamic Programming Practice Problems](http://people.cs.clemson.edu/~bcdean/dp_practice/)

Comment: Seeing this lecture from MIT http://video.mit.edu/watch/introduction-to-algorithms-lecture-19-dynamic-programming-i-fibonacci-shortest-paths-14225/ and then solving the above problems, would help you understand why DP is helpful.

Comment: Case in point the youtube link in the comment is already broken.  New link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQ5jsbhAv_M

Comment: Check out this set of videos which I found it covers both top-down and bottom-up aspect of the algorithms pretty intuitively: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLx-Ye3Zw0WL0O_IDmbcVHlKqJuGEfw3VG

Comment: Looks like MIT moved their content from the main page to the MIT OpenCourseWare page, so the link @pg2286 provided is invalid. The link is now [19. Dynamic Programming I](https://youtu.be/OQ5jsbhAv_M) The full playlist [Introduction to Algorithms](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUl4u3cNGP61Oq3tWYp6V_F-5jb5L2iHb) is also available

Answer (score 21):

[Here is a good tutorial](http://prismoskills.appspot.com/lessons/Dynamic_Programming/Chapter_01_-_Introduction.jsp) comprising 29 solved DP problem with great explanation.

Answer (score 7):

The idea behind dynamic programming is that you're caching (memoizing) solutions to subproblems, though I think there's more to it than that.

There are many Google Code Jam problems such that solutions require dynamic programming to be efficient.  Examples:

[Welcome to Code Jam (moderate)](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=90101#s=p2)

[Cheating a Boolean Tree (moderate)](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=32001#s=p0)

[PermRLE (hard)](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=32001#s=p3)

Note that each of the Code Jam practice contests has a "Contest Analysis" section for if you're stumped trying to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the resources. I solve one or two questions from project euler from time to time, and it seems that I am really stuck at some problems which need knowledge about DP.

Answer (score 5):

1. Geeks for geeks has a great [collection](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tag/dynamic-programming/) of dynamic programming problems. I feel this set is one of the best if you are preparing for interview.
2. If you want small tutorial videos on DP problems you can check [this](http://people.cs.clemson.edu/~bcdean/dp_practice/) problem set from MIT.

Answer (score 4):

Calculating Levenshtein distances was one of the first problems I solved with dynamic programming; I think it is a decent next step from the Fibonacci sequence in terms of complexity.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance