# How to optimize double increment in c?

Tags: c, performance

I am working on C code optimization and there are many calculations which adds 1.0 to the expression which returns double value like

```
val =  1.0 + u[8] / c_sq + (u[8] * u[8]) / (2.0 * c_sq * c_sq) - u_sq / (2.0 * c_sq)
```

so I was just curious to know is there any optimization technique to improve this piece of code.

Comment: Did you measure your code's performance and determine that the adding of `1.0` was causing the predominant bottleneck?

Comment: What exactly does the line of code in your question do? What are the types of each variable? Can you reformat it to make the order-of-operation more apparent?

Comment: @Kerrek, I didn't perform this activity as the method i am working on is huge and involves lot of computation, so I was suspecting about this piece as arithmetic operations on double takes time.

Comment: @Dai, all are of type double.

Comment: Aren't you more worried that you make the same multiplication twice?

Comment: @self, please let me know any other optimization possible in this as well.

Comment: Why not let the compiler optimize this one, and you go figure out where the real bottleneck is?

Comment: (Perhaps not completely a duplicate, but eliminating the unnecessary divisions is the bulk of the work.)

Answer (score 4):

That single line of code, taken on its own without any context whatsoever, is what it is. It cannot be optimized any further as long as the compiler you are using is at least doing [CSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) on the `2.0 * c_sq`. Otherwise, that's pretty much all you can do outside of domain-specific optimizations that aren't apparent by just that code.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination

Comment: Good point, added the abbreviation as a link to that page. I guess someone asking this question likely doesn't know 'CSE'. :)

Comment: Division is very expensive on typical current processors, and [two divisions can eliminated from the expression](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19350996/298225).

Answer (score 2):

On typical current processors, division is time consuming; it can take dozens of CPU cycles. You can rearrange the expression to eliminate two divisions, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19350996/298225). You can make some minor other improvements as well (which the compiler might have caught):

```
double t = u[8];
double v = 2*c_sq;

val = 1 + (t*(v+t) - u_sq*c_sq) / (v*c_sq);
```

Comment: That's not a bad equation-equivalent. +1, assuming the compiler didn't already re-arrange to the equivalent. (Of course, it depends on which compiler and which settings were used for the compiler [i.e. allowing the compiler to re-arrange the calculation, since in some cases, the re-arrangement might result in slightly different results due to precison].)